# Dart: How to initialize function-type field in initializer list?

Tags: dart

I have a class which accept a function as a constructor parameter. I want to define a secondary constructor where the user can provide a static value instead. I did something like this:

```dart
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

class UpdateCheckNotWorking {
  final Function0<Future<String>> versionProvider;

  UpdateCheckNotWorking(this.versionProvider);

  UpdateCheckNotWorking.withStaticVersion(String version)
      : versionProvider = () => Future.value(version);
}
```

This code does not compile because of 2 errors:

[image]
[image]

A workaround is to use a `late final` field and initialize it in the constructor body:

```
class UpdateCheckOk {
  late final Function0<Future<String>> versionProvider;

  UpdateCheckOk(this.versionProvider);

  UpdateCheckOk.withStaticVersion(String version) {
    versionProvider = () => Future.value(version);
  }
}
```

But I am wondering, why is the first implementation not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if you add some parenthesis:

```dart
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

class UpdateCheckOk {
  final Function0<Future<String>> versionProvider;

  UpdateCheckOk(this.versionProvider);

  UpdateCheckOk.withStaticVersion(String version)
      : versionProvider = (() => Future.value(version));
}
```

Comment: Correct. It's a restriction in the grammar. You cannot have a function declaration directly as an initializer list expression, because it gets in the way of parsing a constructor body. Example: `F() : x = (e) {}...` can look like a parenthesized expression and a constructor body, or a single block-body function. So it's not allowed. The arrow functions could work, but because function expressions are disallowed in general, you can't use those either.